# Javascript minification logic where immutable properties are involved

Tags: closures, javascript, yui-compressor

A question on the minifying logic.

```
// Assumptions:
//com.example.dummy ns is available
//com.example.dummy.type is defined immutable -> Object.defineProperty

var test, test1, test2;
function execute_case(id) {
    switch(id) {
    case 0:
       test = com.example.dummy.type;
       break;
    case 1:
       test1 = com.example.dummy.type;
       break;
    case 2:
       test2 = com.example.dummy.type;
       break;
    default:
       console.log("default");
       break;
    }
}
```

the YUI compressor compresses it to,

```
var test,test1,test2;function execute_case(a){switch(a){case 0:
test=com.example.dummy.type;break;case 1:test1=com.example.dummy.type;break;
case 2:test2=com.example.dummy.type;break;default:console.log("default");break}};
```

Wouldn't it be logical for the compressor do the following as an optimization?

```
var test, test1, test2;
var st = com.example.dummy.type;
function execute_case(id) {
    switch(id) {
    case 0:
       test = st;
    case 1:
       test1 = st;
       break;
    case 2:
       test2 = st;
       break;
    default:
       console.log("default");
       break;
    }
}
```

As can be seen, the compression here works out better.

```
var test,test1,test2;var st=com.example.dummy.type;function execute_case(a){
switch(a){case 0:test=st;case 1:test1=st;break;case 2:test2=st;break;
default:console.log("default");break}};
```

Comment: um, sure, that would make sense, i suppose. perhaps some minifiers do do that (they're not all the same). is there a question here?

Comment: @sgroves YUI/GCC in simple mode/JSMin/UglifyJS - not one of them seem to do it. GCC in advanced mode is so demanding code-wise, that it is a very big challenge to get it to work. So, I am not very sure about it yet.

Comment: is this a problem? after i minify something i never look at it again. who cares. if you want to assign `com.example.dummy.type` to a variable outside the function, then YOU should do that (or, god forbid, you could use `with`). or find a minifier that will, or write your own.

Comment: @sgroves From a pure minification perspective - a minifier should try and check it. From a user's perspective - yes, any code that I write, i take care of doing it manually. But I have a large chunk of code - converted/auto-generated and am trying to see if minifier takes care of it automatically. If not, I will take a look at the generator.

Comment: who's to say what a minifier "should" do? some just strip whitespace. some do way more than that. if you can't find one that does what you need, you may need to write your own. either way i don't see a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That optimization makes sense for uncompressed source code, but not if the file is delivered with gzip compression (which is highly recommended).

String aliasing tends to make the compressed source code larger.

See the [Closure-compiler FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#Closure_Compiler_inlined_all_my_strings,_which_made_my_code_size)